# Mage_Core_Block_Abstract vs Mage_Core_Block_Template

Tags: blocks, widgets

What is the difference between Mage_Core_Block_Abstract and Mage_Core_Block_Template?  When would I want to use each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mage_Core_Block_Template extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract. The only time you'd want to extend directly from the abstract is when you want to fundamentally want to change how the block is rendered in some way.

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if (!$this->getTemplate()) {
        return '';
    }
    $html = $this->renderView();
    return $html;
}
```

The _toHtml() is called in Template, this in turn ultimately leads to the method fetchView() which does not exist within the abstract block. So you would need to therefore implement that or an equivalent to return an output.